# How to access a KinectSensorchooser object on an xaml file in a different cs file?

Tags: wpf, kinect

I am a  beginner in WPF and c#.I am trying to create an application using Kinect for Windows. I have a kinectsensorchooser in my Kinect.cs and it controls the SensorChooser in the MainWindow.xaml
But I am not sure how to control it.
My code is as follows:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Canvas>  
<k:KinectSensorChooserUI KinectSensorChooser="{Binding SCkinectSensorChooser} "Name="sensorChooserCP"/>  
<k:KinectUserViewer k:KinectRegion.KinectRegion="{Binding kinectRegionCP}"/>  
<k:KinectRegion Name="kinectRegionCP" KinectSensor="{Binding ElementName=SCkinectsensor}">  
<Grid>  
some kinect tile buttons come in here...  
</Grid>  
</k:KinectRegion>  
</Canvas>
```

**Kinect.cs**

```
public KinectSensor SCkinectsensor;  
public KinectSensorChooser SCkinectSensorChooser;
```

the values of the two objects will be set dynamically during the program execution. I want these changes to be reflected in the MainWindow

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="Kinect.App"  
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"  
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kinect">  
<Application.Resources>  
<local:Kinect x:Key="Kinect" />  
</Application.Resources>
```

I am doing something wrong and the code is not responding as I wish... What should I do? I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting your `DataContext` in the main window? If not, your `Binding` will do nothing.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Kinect.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{StaticResource Kinect}">
...
</Window>
```

Another thing to note, is that in WPF, you can only bind to **properties**.

**Kinect.cs**

```
public KinectSensor SCkinectsensor { get; private set; }
public KinectSensorChooser SCkinectSensorChooser { get; private set; }
```

If you expect these properties to change outside of the constructor, then this class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and your properties would look like this:

```
private KinectSensor kinectSensor;
public KinectSensor SCkinectSensor
{
    get { return kinectSensor; }
    set 
    {
        kinectSensor = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SCkinectSensor");
    }
}
```