# Binding based on Condition

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, kinect

I have been developing a simple application in C# that uses Kinect hand pointer for controls.

In my application I have more than 6 canvases,In every canvas I have embedded a Kinect region. I bind the kinectsensor in mainwindow.cs to the KinectRegions in the canvases.

```
<Canvas Name=" Canvas1" Visibility="Visible">
<k:KinectRegion KinectSensor="{Binding kinectSensor}" Name="kinectRegionCP">
// some controls
</Canvas>
<Canvas Name=" Canvas1" Visibility="Hidden">
<k:KinectRegion KinectSensor="{Binding kinectSensor}" Name="kinectRegionAP">
// some controls
</Canvas>
.........// some more canvases
```

The problem is ,Even-though only one canvas is visible at a time,the CPU usage burst to 90% as all other canvases are actively using the kinect region.

Is there any way to bind the sensor only when the particular Canvas is visible?

Comment: It might help us if you post some of the code-behind.

Comment: from the code behind, you can disable other elements while only one you chose is active.

Comment: @ZachSmith In my code I have changed the canvases on some conditions(i.e after face recognition,user clicked the settings button etc).Isn't there any other way to bind Kinectsensor based on the visiblity of the Canvas ,in XAML itself?

Comment: @Naresh Are you suggesting to do the binding in the code?

Comment: no. I had similar situation, where I have multiple instances of same controls, and I need only one at a time. So when I select one instance, in the code behind, I disabled (change visibility) other controls.

Comment: @Naren Xaml's not very dynamic in that sense. You need to change the bindings in the code-behind.

Comment: @Naresh Sorry I could't get it?Can you explain it a little further?

Comment: @ZachSmith Now I use these BindingOperations.SetBinding(kinectRegionCP,KinectRegion.KinectSensorProperty, myBinding) ..but I have to do it in the code behind by checking the visibility of pages and unbind it..

Comment: I assume you need only one canvas at a time. Call it "can1". Now when you are using "can1", you can set the visibility of others to "Hidden". Something like "can2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;" in the code behind. This code you can implement whereever required. For example for testing can1, you can set all canvas to hidden in MainWindow(). Try.

Comment: @Naresh Yes I can set the visibility of all unused canvases to "hidden".I thought in XAML we can bind based on condition(Visiblity of canvas)..But it seems there is no way of doing it in XAML,Now as you suggested I have done that in the code behind.

Comment: you can do it in XAML too. but then visibility will be bound to some property that will be changing every time you select a canvas. I used MVVM concept when I dont have a handle on the events. If you can attach an event, then you can simply trigger changes in the code behind. I am not expert though. I do things which work for now. later I learn better ways and improve.

Comment: @Naresh Thanks ! This is good,the idea of binding the visibility,As of now I am doing the binding from code behind and its working..Later I will try to implement the binding on Visiblity of Canvas..Can u tell me how to bind the visibility with Kinectsensor ,so I can use it later?

Comment: Binding is a general concept. If you know how to bind one object, you know how to bind others. Just keep in mind, binding is always bound to one instance and is always bound to a property. People make this mistake in the beginning. I recommend have a look here : http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2008/10/27/binding-converters---visibilityconverter.aspx

Comment: @Naresh Thanks!! I will definitely have a look at that link..

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `DataContext` based on the `Visibility` of the control. Here is an example on the `Canvas`. If you have other controls on the `Canvas` that are databound you will need to apply the `Style` to `k:KinectRegion`.

```
<Canvas Name=" Canvas1" Visibility="Visible">
<Canvas.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Canvas">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden">
                <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Canvas.Style>
<k:KinectRegion KinectSensor="{Binding kinectSensor}" Name="kinectRegionCP">
    // some controls
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your class and try setting up the bindings like so:

```
private KinectSensor _kinectSensor1;
public KinectSensor kinectSensor1
{
    get { return _kinectSensor1; }
    private set; //assuming you don't really need to set it from the XAML
}
```

Then whenever you want to bind or unbind it just:

```
_kinectSensor1 = new KinectSensor()
RaisePropertyChanged("kinectSensor1");
```

After looking around I found another answer implementing the same thing here: [How to access a KinectSensorchooser object on an xaml file in a different cs file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368309/how-to-access-a-kinectsensorchooser-object-on-an-xaml-file-in-a-different-cs-fil)

Comment: ,I have used the INotifyPropertyChanged and it's working fine..The problem is a single kinect sensor is binded with the kinect regions of all canvases,I need to bind them only if the canvas is visible...